# Adding values to dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

So I have this code, but it is not outputting, after adding 4th value, the right stuff, it's like it all gets deleted and it is not added until the next run

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 2;

void addValue(int data[], int& logSize, int& physSize, int newValue)
{
    // DATA DICTIONARY
    int *temp;

    if (logSize == physSize)
    {
        physSize *= 2;
        temp = new int[physSize];

        for (int i = 0; i <= logSize; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = data[i];
            cout<<temp[i]<<endl;
        }

        delete [] data;
        data = temp;
    }

    data[logSize] = newValue;

    for (int i = 0; i <= logSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<data[i]<<endl;
    }

    logSize++;
}

void printData(int data[], int logSize)
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"ARRAY DATA:"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < logSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<data[i]<<endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    //DATA DICTIONARY
    int *data;
    int logSize;
    int physSize;
    int newValue;
    char choice;

    physSize = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    logSize = 0;
    data = new int[physSize];

    do
    {
        cout<<"What would you like to do?"<<endl;
        cout<<"(A)dd value to array"<<endl;
        cout<<"(D)isplay all values"<<endl;
        cout<<"(Q)uit"<<endl;

        cin>>choice;

        if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
        {
            cout<<"What integer do you want to add? ";
            cin>>newValue;
            addValue(data, logSize, physSize, newValue);
        }

        if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
        {
            printData(data, logSize);
        }

        cout<<endl;

    } while (choice != 'Q' && choice != 'q');
}
```

Comment: Use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). C++ argument passing is often [pass by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass-by-value) unless you explicitly use references (and you can't have references to arrays)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - this is for an assignment, cannot use vectors on it.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Can you be a little more specific about what's going on? Provide basic output etc...

Comment: Essentially: what is wrong with my code? When I run it, I can add the first 3 values fine, but then, it outputs gibberish as if the array is null/empty

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Learn to **use a debugger** (`gdb`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you could and should use an `std::vector<int>` aside, `data` is being passed as a pointer *by value* here:

```
void addValue(int data[], int& logSize, int& physSize, int newValue)
```

(for `int data[]`, read `int* data`). So `addValue has its own copy of the pointer, and whatever it does with it has no effect on the caller side. You can fix this particular problem by passing the pointer by reference:

```
void addValue(int*& data, int& logSize, int& physSize, int newValue)
```

Comment: Right on! Worked perfectly, thanks. Guess I need to review this whole operation of how pointers and stuff work.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `data` by [reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp121.linux.doc%2Flanguage_ref%2Fcplr233.html). You are passing it by value.